# Como configurar vários sistemas em um domínio?

Tags: laravel, aplicação-web, apache

Tenho domínio www.meusite.com.br

Gostaria de hospedar vários sistemas nesse domínio. Ficando assim:

www.meusite.com.br/sistema1

www.meusite.com.br/sistema2

www.meusite.com.br/sistema3

Uso o virtualhost assim:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName meusite.com.br
  ServerAlias www.meusite.com.br
  ServerAdmin meuemail@meusite.com.br
  DocumentRoot "/var/www"   


Alias /sistema1 "/var/www/sistema1/public"
   <Directory "/var/www/sistema1/public">
     AllowOverride All
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
     Order deny,allow
     Allow from all
   </Directory>

Alias /sistema2 "/var/www/sistema2/public"
   <Directory "/var/www/sistema2/public">
     AllowOverride All
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
     Order deny,allow
     Allow from all
   </Directory>
```

Troco o .htaccess de cada um dos projetos para isso:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    **RewriteBase /sistema1**

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

O sistema são todos em laravel. Está funcionando dessa forma acima, porém, acho que não é a abordagem correta. Em um outro projeto que estamos usando, está apresentando erros nas url's das chamadas ajax. Sou estudante e preciso configurar esse servidor da universidade para hospedar outros sistemas nesse domínio.

Poderiam me orientar em qual abordagem utilizar ou o que devo começar a estudar? Não tenho muito conhecimento, preciso de uma direção.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cada sistema com seu próprio subdomínio e um `VirtualHost` para cada um:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@meusite.com.br

    ServerName sistema1.meusite.com.br

    DocumentRoot /var/www/sistema1/public
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/sistema1-error.log

    <Directory /var/www/sistema1/public>
            Options -Indexes
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

E o próximo é:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@meusite.com.br

    ServerName sistema2.meusite.com.br

    DocumentRoot /var/www/sistema2/public
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/sistema2-error.log

    <Directory /var/www/sistema2/public>
            Options -Indexes
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

E cada virtualhost com um arquivo de configuração diferente:

`/etc/apache2/sites-available/sistema1.conf`

`/etc/apache2/sites-available/sistema2.conf`

Pode até parecer trabalhoso ficar apontando muitos registros de DNS, mas essa abordagem separa cada uma das aplicações de maneira eficiente. Podendo até mesmo ativar e desativar qualquer um deles sem afetar o todo.

E caso você tenha que compartilhar o núcleo da aplicação entre todos aponte tudo para o mesmo diretório e seu sistema deve verificar qual é o hostname certo e trabalhar com os dados corretos. (Não recomendaria)

E, por fim, você pode escrever um Shell Script que automatize a criação destes arquivos de configuração.

E ainda você não deixa de usar um único domínio, só está utilizando ele de forma diferente de como pensou inicialmente.

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção. Vou fazer como você falou, mas o problema é a coordenadora quer que os endereços sejam como eu falei: www.meusite.com.br/sistema1 etc. É possível fazer de outra forma da que eu fiz ?

Comment: Eu apresentaria para sua coordenadora as vantagens em questões de segurança de isolar uma aplicação de outra, mas pensando na solução que está propondo acredito que a configuração RewriteBase não tem que ter asteriscos. Me fala mais sobre o comportamento que acontece quando roda essa configuração que tento te ajudar..

Comment: Amigo, conseguir resolver meu problema com relação as urls ajax. Vou propor o que você me disse. Abraço